# React: How to loop through object?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, loops, object, frontend

[image]

patient.users returns
[image]

patients.users it's an array of objects but I cannot loop through it. When I was trying to call patients.users[0] it returned "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')". Why is that?

```
function DoctorPanel() {
const location = useLocation();
const { id } = location.state;
const [patients, setPatiens] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  getPatients();
}, [])

const getPatients = () => {
  api.getDoctorById(id).then(response => {
    setPatiens(response.data)
})

 }

console.log(patients.users)



return (

<div>
    <div className="container">
      <h2 className="text-center">List of Patients</h2>
      <table className="table table-bordered table-striped">
          <thead>
              <th>Employee First Name</th>
              <th>Employee Last Name</th>
              <th>Number</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {
              patients.users.map(patient => 
                      <tr>
                          <td>{patient.firstName}</td>
                           <td>{patient.secondName}</td>
                           <td>{patient.number}</td>
                      </tr>
               )
            }
          </tbody>
      </table>    
  </div>
</div>
```

)
}

for loop, forEach, and with Object.keys don't work as well. How I can loop through it and display the details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because there is nothing in the `patients.users` array when you first render this component, so it says cannot read properties of undefined which is your array.

You then get the data in the `useEffect` which is run after the first render.

What you need to do is anywhere you access `patients.users` change to either:

`patient?.users` or `patient && patient.users`, this includes your console.log. What this does is check that `patient` array is not undefined before trying to access `users` on it.

EDIT:

Its also best practice in a `useEffect` to put the code in there rather than calling a function which exists outside. And you have a typo in the state setter `setPatiens` should be `setPatients`.

Comment: It helps, thank you a lot and I'll take your advice into account :)